# Run Jobs Sequentially, in the Background, in Bash

Tags: bash, background-process

I'm writing a bash script to execute a python program with different values of parameters 'H' and 'K'. What I would like to happen is that only one instance of 'program.py' runs at a time and subsequent jobs are not started until the previous one finishes.

Here's what I tried -

```
#!/bin/bash

H="1 10 100"

K="0.01 0.1"

for H_val in ${H}
do
        for K_val in ${K}
        do
               { nohup python program.py $H_val $K_val; } &
        done
done
```

However, this just loops over all the parameter values without waiting for any one job to finish. Conversely, if I modify the above slightly by taking off the ampersand, I can run each job individually - but not in the background. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: What's the point of "in the background" when you want sequential?

Comment: (...as a completely different matter -- don't use nohup; it's 100% pointless, and does not a single thing that bash can't do itself).

Comment: ...to be more clear about what I was saying about nohup -- it's basically equivalent to adding `</dev/null >nohup.out 2>&1 & disown -h` to the end of a command; hardcoding the filename `nohup.out` is generally more a bug than a feature (you should use a unique name, typically one with a timestamp!) and the `disown` part is only needed at all in interactive shells, as noninteractive ones don't pay attention to HUP in the first place.

Comment: I'm a greybeard who started using UNIX around 1984. Back then when you often connected to a computer over a single serial connection being able to background processes was important. I haven't backgrounded a job in the past 20 years. There are much better alternatives today. Such as using `tmux` or your terminal's ability to have multiple tabs/windows. As Duffy pointed out your script is explicitly placing jobs into the background without waiting for them to finish (done using the `wait` builtin). But if you want them to run sequentially why background them at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the `&` on the command you want to put in the background. In this context, that might be your whole loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- ensures that array support is available

hValues=( 1 10 100 ) # best practice is to iterate over array elements, not...
kValues=( 0.01 0.1 ) # ...words in strings!

{
  # perform conditional redirections akin to what nohup would do
  [ -t 0 ] && exec </dev/null      # stdin
  [ -t 1 ] && exec >myprogram.log  # stdout
  [ -t 2 ] && exec 2>&1            # stderr

  for hVal in "${hValues[@]}"; do
    for kVal in "${kValues[@]}"; do
      python program.py "$hVal" "$kVal"
    done
  done
} &
```

Notice how the `&` was moved to be after the `done` -- that way we background the entire loop, not a single command within it, so the backgrounded process -- running that loop -- invokes only one copy of the Python interpreter at a time.

The redirections (`</dev/null`, `>myprogram.log`, and `2>&1`) are equivalent to how nohup would redirect stdout and stderr to `nohup.out` if they weren't already going to a file (or other non-TTY destination) to ensure that they aren't attached to a TTY; adjust the name `myprogram.log` to your preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [task spooler](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/tsp.1.html), it creates a queue of jobs to run and launches them one at a time, in order of submission (by default). When submitting a new job, it returns an assigned ID that you can further use to optionally add constraints; for example running a job only if another exited successfully. It also stores each job output stream separately.

Your script would then be:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

H="1 10 100"

K="0.01 0.1"

for H_val in "${H}"
do
    for K_val in "${K}"
    do
        tsp python program.py "${H_val}" "${K_val}"
    done
done
```

or more concisely, if you are set on doing the full parameter search, using `parallel` to avoid the explicit nested loops:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

H=(1 10 100)
K=(0.01 0.1)

# fill the queue with all parameter combinations
parallel tsp python program.py ::: "${H[@]}" ::: "${K[@]}" >/dev/null
```

After running your script, you can supervise the progression by calling `tsp` without arguments, and you can see the output of a job with `tsp -c <jobID>`.